# Adding multiple values into a single key in swift?

Tags: swift, collections, keyvaluepair

When I try to add multiple values to the key, my value gets overridden by the last value I assigned to the key. I tried adding brackets between the value `String` of my [String: **[String]**] key-value pair. I did that to hopefully achieve the effect to add multiple values into that key.

```
import UIKit

var parent = [String: [String]]()
parent["parent"] = ["Tommy Turner", "Wolfgang Motart"]
parent["parent"] = ["Bobby Bushe"]
print(parent)

// How can I add multiple values into the parent key like this:
//      ["parent": "Tommy Turner", "Wolgang Motart", "Bobby Bushe"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the type of `parent["parent"]` is array of string, you can use append function for adding one or multiple elements. Try this.

```
var parent = [String: [String]]()
parent["parent"] = ["Tommy Turner", "Wolfgang Motart"]
parent["parent"]?.append("bob") // append one element to become ["Tommy Turner", "Wolfgang Motart", "bob"]
parent["parent"]?.appendContentsOf(["hello", "world"]) // append collection
print(parent["parent"]!) // ["Tommy Turner", "Wolfgang Motart", "bob", "hello", "world"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add new array to previous like:

```
var parent = [String: [String]]()
parent["parent"] = ["Tommy Turner", "Wolfgang Motart"]
parent["parent"] = (parent["parent"] ?? []) + ["Bobby Bushe"]
print(parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not combine the [string] and  assign to the key：

```
var parent = [String: [String]]()
let value = ["Tommy Turner", "Wolfgang Motart"] + ["Bobby Bushe"]
parent["parent"] = value
print(parent) // ["parent": ["Tommy Turner", "Wolfgang Motart", "Bobby Bushe"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the key of "parent" in this key-value pairing. If you want it to have those three names, just put all three names in the array.

```
parent["parent"] = ["Name", "name", "nombre"]
```

If you were to create an array outside of scope, and set the value for "parent"

```
var namesArray = ["Name", "name"]
parent["parent"] = namesArray
namesArray.append("nombre")
```

It would still only print out `["Name", "name"]`. However, if you were to call

```
parent["parent"] = namesArray
```

again, it would create what you want.